# testng.xml is not executing when we run pom.xml for maven project selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven, pom

While executing my pom.xml file through maven test my BUILD is getting SUCCESSFUL but my testng.xml is not executing.

[image]

I tried with executing 13 classes and with single class for both the time it gives the same result.
I don't know why it is copying 0 resource.

Please check my **pom.xml** below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>e-Pragati_App_Store</groupId>
  <artifactId>e-Pragati_App_Store</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please follow my **testng.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Usecase1">
        <classes>
            <class name="APp_Store.AddNewAppErrorMessages"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: What is the full path to your testng.xml starting from project root?

Comment: i too had same problem. its worked for me. i copied the file in resources. thanks @Aulis

Answer (score 2):

The testng.xml should be located in your test resources. That way the testng.xml will be copied. You can also configure surefire plugin to explicitly run  testng suite xml files. Should your maven plugins be configured as plugins not dependencies? Also seems like you should have other dependencies in test scope as well.

Be sure to check that your test classes have postfix 'Test'.

Comment: Mine worked by using suffix as Test. Just a quick question, why is this needed though ? Does Maven needs it or TestNG ?

Answer (score 0):

Include maven surefire plugin end of the properties & before the dependencies. Use your "TestNG" XML file name.Use below code.

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```